# Why are there (roughly, at least) equal numbers of electrons and protons in the universe, despite their hugely differing masses?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, electrons, protons

Other people have asked very similar questions, but I cannot find an explanation or question referring to their vastly differing masses (approx. 1836 to 1)....

Also, if there are almost 2000 times as many electrons as protons in the universe, where are they all?

How come the 'Missing Electron Problem' isn't as famous as the Missing Lithium Puzzle or the Missing Baryonic Mattery Mystery or Matter-Antimatter Asymmetry....

Comment: Your middle statement doesn't seem to follow from anything, why do you think there are 2000 times more electrons than protons?

Comment: Why is the proton / electron mass ratio relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Because charge is conserved and the universe appears to have no net charge. You could replace electrons with other negatively charged leptons (because lepton number is also conserved), but these are unstable (in most circumstances) and would decay into electrons.

The mass ratio is only relevant in so far as determining things like when and where the protons and electrons are produced and that the electron, being the lightest charged lepton, is the "ground state".